# Maximization bias in reinforcement learning

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, bias, reinforcement-learning, unbiased-estimator

In Richard S. Sutton and Andrew G. Barto's book on reinforcement learning on page 156 it says:

> Maximization bias occurs when estimate the value function while taking max on it (that is what Q learning do), and maximization may not take on the true value which may introduce bias.

1. Why can double Q learning solve this problem, and what is the proof for that?
2. Does maximization bias always underestimate or always overestimate the true value? Why?

Comment: always overestimates, because of the max() operation

Comment: Maybe you refer to Jensen inequality, but why it's convex and convex respect to which variable?

Answer (score 2):

One way to view the problem of maximizing bias is that it is due to using the same samples both to determine the maximizing action and to estimate its value. So, we decouple in two policies Q<sub>1</sub>(a) and Q<sub>2</sub>(a) and choose, say Q<sub>1</sub>(a) to choose maximizing action and Q<sub>2</sub>(a) to estimate its value.